# How to find the value of $\alpha$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $M$ be a $3 \times 3 $ matrix such that

$M \begin{bmatrix} -2 \\
1\\
0\end{bmatrix}$ = $\begin{bmatrix} 6 \\
-3\\
0\end{bmatrix}$   and suppose that

$M^3 \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\
-1/2\\
0\end{bmatrix}$ = $\begin{bmatrix} \alpha \\
\beta\\
\gamma\end{bmatrix}$  for some $\alpha, \beta,\gamma \in R$ then

$\left|\alpha\right|$ is equal to :

I have figured out that 
$\begin{bmatrix} -2 \\
1\\
0\end{bmatrix}$ is an eigen vector of given matrix with eigen value  equal to $-3$ .

But I am stuck after that step. Can somebody help

Thank you.

Comment: You mean eigenvalue $-3$, right?

Comment: Also notice that if $v$ is an eigenvector, also $\zeta \cdot v$ will be an eigenvector for any constant $\zeta$ since eigenvectors are precisely those vectors whose length but not direction is changed by applying the matrix.

Comment: @sat091:  You're new here.  Let me strongly recommend you use titles that are informative and help others find this problem (and solution).  $\alpha$ could refer to *anything* in *any* branch of mathematics.  A much better title would be something along the lines of "Solving equations involving powers of matrix."

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* If $v$ is an eigenvector of a matrix $A$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$, the it is also an eigenvector of $A^3$ with eigenvalue $\lambda^3$.

Comment: so, $-27$ will  be an eigen value of $M^3$ and thus $\alpha = -27, \beta = 27/2, \gamma = 0$ is this correct ?

Comment: @sat091 Yes, that is correct.